# Is this sequence in "Star Trek" (2009) a reference to a Hoth sequence from "The Empire Strikes Back"?

Tags: star-wars, reference, star-trek, the-empire-strikes-back, star-trek-2009

In the Kelvenverse timeline, which begins in *Star Trek* (2009), there is a sequence where alter-Spock attempts to rid himself and the Enterprise crew of alter-James T. Kirk, after getting off to a rocky start.

He deserts Kirk on a snowy planetoid where there is a Federation outpost called Delta-Vega outpost. But before he discovers this information from a prime Spock, he is chased by an alien baboon-like creature, in which then another comes (Hengrauggi Monster), attacks the first creature and then continues to go after Kirk until Spock Prime comes out of a cave with a torch lit.

This sequence however seems a little familiar reminding me of Luke Skywalker's sequences against a Wampa on Hoth in *Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back*. There is also a similar sequence in *The Phantom Menace* where a fish species is after Qui-gon, Obi-wan, and Jar Jar in their underwater speeder, but another larger fish comes and eats the smaller one. Qui-gon comments, *"There's always a bigger fish."*

In addition *Star Trek*'s following cave scene where Kirk gets knowledge and wisdom from the older Prime Spock is a similar concept to Luke getting knowledge from the wise and old Yoda, along with the cave on Dagobah, also featured in *The Empire Strikes Back*.

J. J. Abrams is also a well-known *Star Wars* fan, with references in almost every Bad Robot TV series, most notably *LOST*, while he has also now directed and co-wrote two Skywalker Saga films!

[image: Kirk and Spock in a posture similar to Luke and Yoda's]

So my question is, are these sequences reference to *Star Wars*, mostly *The Empire Strikes Back*? Is there a source to back these potential allusions up?

Comment: Do you think SW-ESB did these well used tropes first?

Comment: You mean first ever?? No, not necessarily or even likely, but my thinking relies on being an Abrams/Bad Robot fan, a Star Wars fan, that the sequence also takes place on an ice planet, additional similar concepts where wisdom is passed is used in relation to caves, and the fact that Star Wars is "iconic" and may be the most recognizable of said tropes. I tried to set up context in the way I framed the Q, but I will gladly take answers that go beyond Star Wars, if that IS where the answer I seek lies.